# JavaScript doughnut chart with centered hover label

Tags: javascript, svg, html5-canvas, raphael, chart.js

I am trying to create this chart with `chart.js` or `raphael`. I am expecting, on hover the label will show up exactly as that image. I created it with `chart.js` but unable to implement the inner style and hover functionality. Can anybody help please? Thanks in advance
[image: Custom doughnut chart]

Its the solution i found [jsfiddle.net/sajibsrs/u6rr5moq/186](http://jsfiddle.net/sajibsrs/u6rr5moq/186) but unable to get the style and implement hover functionality.

Comment: can you implement this in jsfiddle?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking me to do.

Comment: Just like I am providing a link below: https://jsfiddle.net/cmyker/u6rr5moq/

Comment: WOW. That was close. I want the centered texts to be styled as the image and it will get changed on hover. As now its showing the percentages and yes i want to disable the tool tip. Please let me know if its clear enough for you. Thanks

Comment: you should include the code you have so far in the question.

Comment: Its the solution i found https://jsfiddle.net/sajibsrs/u6rr5moq/186/ but unable to get the style and implement hover functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i was able to solve my problem. Here is the basic functionality i was looking for and i'll further refine the code and its functionality.

`Link:` https://jsfiddle.net/sajibsrs/m2a7ovje/